# WPForms Custom Redirect not working

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, forms

I use WPForms in one product category where customers get redirected to cart after filling in the form. The WPForms redirection where you set the URL works perfectly, however, I need the URL to be dynamic.

I found a git with the script that I need and applied it to my functions.php:

```
function wpf_custom_redirect( $url, $form_id, $fields ) {

    // Only consider changing the redirect if its for form #50
    $variation_id = 0;
    $url = get_site_url();
    if ( '797' == $form_id ) {

        // In the example below, we look at the submitted value for field #5
        // If that value is "test", then we change the redirect URL
        if ( !empty( $fields['4']['value'] ) && 2 == $fields['4']['value'] ) { //birthdays
            $variation_id = 806;
        } else if ( !empty( $fields['4']['value'] ) && 1 == $fields['4']['value'] ) { //encouragement
            $variation_id = 807;
        } else if ( !empty( $fields['4']['value'] ) && 4 == $fields['4']['value'] ) { //spiritual
            $variation_id = 809;
        } else if ( !empty( $fields['4']['value'] ) && 5 == $fields['4']['value'] ) { //greeting
            $variation_id = 810;
        } else if ( !empty( $fields['4']['value'] ) && 6 == $fields['4']['value'] ) { //holiday
            $variation_id = 808;
        }

        $url .= '/cart?add-to-cart=82&variation_id='.$variation_id;
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpforms_process_redirect_url', 'wpf_custom_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

I also made sure that my child theme is working and my functions.php is being used.

What could be the issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!
-Eli

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `wpforms_process_redirect_url` doesn't work. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275790/custom-php-code-to-deal-with-wpform-field-input) instead.

Here's my full code:

```
//Capture the wpform submit, and call the "processForm" function
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', 'processForm', 5, 4 );

function processForm( $form_fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {

    $card_arr = array(797, 1104, 1103, 1102, 1101, 1038, 997, 996, 973, 812);
    $form_id = $form_data['id'];
    $variation_id = 0;
    $url = get_site_url();

    // Get the full entry object
    $entry = wpforms()->entry->get( $entry_id );

    // Fields are in JSON, so we decode to an array
    $entry_fields = json_decode( $entry->fields, true );

    //$form_data contains the user inputs
    //here you could validate your form
    if(!in_array($form_id, $card_arr)) {
        exit();
    } else if ( in_array($form_id, $card_arr)) {
        if($form_id == 797){
            if ( $entry_fields[4]['value_raw'] == 2 ) { //birthdays
                $variation_id = 806;
            }
            if ( $entry_fields[4]['value_raw'] == 1 ) { //encouragement
                $variation_id = 807;
            }
            if ( $entry_fields[4]['value_raw'] == 4 ) { //spiritual
                $variation_id = 809;
            }
            if ( $entry_fields[4]['value_raw'] == 5 ) { //greeting
                $variation_id = 810;
            }
            if ( $entry_fields[4]['value_raw'] == 6 ) { //holiday
                $variation_id = 808;
            }
        }
        $url .= '/cart/?add-to-cart=82&variation_id='.$variation_id;
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit();
    }
}
```